# Remove event listener from another event target

Tags: javascript, removeeventlistener

I try to remove an event listener from another event target :

-I can remove the event to the red element from this "red event" // I can remove the event to the green element from this "green event".

-But I can't remove the event to the green element from the "red event" // I can't remove the event to the red element from the "green event",   and I don't understand why.

How can I remove all events listener after the first click on one of the elements ?

```js
var clickred = 0;
var clickgreen = 0;
var elemRed = document.getElementById("js-click-me-red");
var elemGreen = document.getElementById("js-click-me-green");

elemRed.addEventListener("click", function h() {
  clickred++;
  if (clickred >= 3) {
    elemGreen.removeEventListener("click", h);
    elemRed.removeEventListener("click", h);
  }

  // debug only
  document.getElementById("js-debug-red").innerHTML += "click<br>";
});

elemGreen.addEventListener("click", function h() {
  clickgreen++;
  if (clickgreen >= 3) {
    elemRed.removeEventListener("click", h);
    elemGreen.removeEventListener("click", h);
  }

  // debug only
  document.getElementById("js-debug-green").innerHTML += "click<br>";
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#js-debug-red {
  color: red;
}

#js-debug-green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <article>
    <div id='js-click-me-red' style='width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: red'></div>
    <div id='js-debug-red'></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div id='js-click-me-green' style='width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: green'></div>
    <div id='js-debug-green'></div>
  </article>
</body>
```

Comment: You're creating an anonymous function in `addEventListener`. Removing even listeners in this way requires you to pass the reference of the function. Quick forked example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/d6c4vfpn/). More info on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener#matching_event_listeners_for_removal)

Comment: The name `h` is local to that function expression. So in `elemRed` you're removing the red `h` listener, in `elemGreen` you're removing the green `h` listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the functions outside the `addEventListener` so you have global names for them, and give different names to the two listeners.

```js
var clickred = 0;
var clickgreen = 0;
var elemRed = document.getElementById("js-click-me-red");
var elemGreen = document.getElementById("js-click-me-green");

elemRed.addEventListener("click", redListener);

elemGreen.addEventListener("click", greenListener);

function redListener() {
  clickred++;
  if (clickred >= 3) {
    removeAllListeners();
  }

  // debug only
  document.getElementById("js-debug-red").innerHTML += "click<br>";
}

function greenListener() {
  clickgreen++;
  if (clickgreen >= 3) {
    removeAllListeners();
  }

  // debug only
  document.getElementById("js-debug-green").innerHTML += "click<br>";
}

function removeAllListeners() {
  elemGreen.removeEventListener("click", greenListener);
  elemRed.removeEventListener("click", redListener);
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#js-debug-red {
  color: red;
}

#js-debug-green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <article>
    <div id='js-click-me-red' style='width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: red'></div>
    <div id='js-debug-red'></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div id='js-click-me-green' style='width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: green'></div>
    <div id='js-debug-green'></div>
  </article>
</body>
```